# Integrate $\int \cosh^4(7x) dx$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions, substitution

Can you help me with solving this integral $$\int \cosh^4(7x) \, dx \text{ ?}$$ I tried use subs but i got 
$$\cosh^4(t)=m$$
$$t = \pm\operatorname{arccosh}^{-1}(m^{1/4})$$
$$dt = \pm\operatorname{arccosh}(m^{1/4})\frac14m^{{-3/4}} \, dm$$

What now?

Comment: Try $\cosh t=(e^t+e^{-t})/2$, and then expand the fourth power, before integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute  $\cosh (7x)=\large \frac{e^{7x}+e^{-7x}}{2}$, $$\int \cosh^4 (7x)\ dx=\int \left(\frac{e^{7x}+e^{-7x}}{2}\right)^4\ dx$$ $$=\int \frac{e^{28x}+e^{-28x}+e^{14x}+e^{-14x}+6}{16}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{e^{28x}}{28}-\frac{e^{-28x}}{28}+\frac{e^{14x}}{14}-\frac{e^{-14x}}{14}+6x\right)+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{\sinh (28x)}{28}+\frac{\sinh (14x)}{14}+6x\right)+C$$

Comment: wow really elegant solution :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\cosh^2x=\frac{1+\cosh2x}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT...use the "double angle" identity $$\cosh^2A=\frac 12(1+\cosh 2A) $$ **twice** to get the integrand in terms of multiple angles

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As for trigonometric functions, the solution is to linearise first:
\begin{align*}\cosh^4u&=\frac1{16}(\mathrm e^u+\mathrm e^{-u})^4=\frac1{16}(\mathrm e^{4u}+4\mathrm e^{2u}+6+4\mathrm e^{-2u}+\mathrm e^{-4u})\\
&=\frac18\cosh4u+\frac12\cosh2u+\frac38.
\end{align*}